# Schedule Tasks in JavaScript (Node webkit project)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm developing a native app using Node webkit. As usually everything goes with JS.
 what i need is: i want to schedule a task using "schtask" command. so that i need to run it from JS code.
Is there any way to run commands from JavaScript code?? or any other alternative to set schedule tasks in windows from Java Script?
- Thanks in advance

Comment: if you are using `node-webkit` you can use node-modules like `child_process`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Actually i'm new to node.js. that is the problem. can you show me a kind of sample code or resources??

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `node-webkit` you can use `node-modules` like `child_process`.

Here is a sample code how to run a `ls` command.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn, // requiring child_process
    ls    = spawn('ls', ['-l', '.']); // created a process for ls the arguments in []

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});
```

[Here](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) are the references

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. :)
I would really feel happy if you try to execute window commands.
anyway it's helpful :)

Comment: i tried replacing Windows command. it's not working @Mritunjay ..
Replaced 'ls' with 'dir' and removed arguments. It shows some error while running app. like this ::

Uncaught node.js Error 

Error: spawn ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:742:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1027:32)
    at child_process.js:1110:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:279:11)

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer in google..
It works PERFECT!

```
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var cp = spawn(process.env.comspec, ['/c', 'command', '-arg1', '-arg2']);
    cp.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
    });
    cp.stderr.on("data", function(data) {
    console.error(data.toString());
    });
```

Thanks for your guidence @Mritunjay :)